# Date format using gviz_api.py

Tags: python, google-visualization

I'm using gviz_api (google-visualization-python)  to build some line charts. 
http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-python/

I'e edited a line chart example taken from the google documentation.
However, I'm not sure how I would pass a date into the DataTable

Here's the edited example I've been working with. 
https://gist.github.com/3941946

Here's the code I had a question about

```
 # Creating the data
 description = {"year": ("string", "Year"),
             "sales": ("number", "Sales"),
             "expenses": ("number", "Expenses")}

 data = [{"year": '2004', "sales": 1000, "expenses": 300}, 
      {"year": '2005', "sales": 1200, "expenses": 400}, 
      {"year": '2006', "sales": 1300, "expenses": 500}, 
      {"year": '2007', "sales": 1400, "expenses": 600}, 
      {"year": '2008', "sales": 1500, "expenses": 800}]
  # Loading it into gviz_api.DataTable
  data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(description)
  data_table.LoadData(data)
```

How would I load a date into the DataTable using gviz_api?

The google documentation describes how to creat a new Date() using javascript, however, I'd like to keep using gviz_api.py.

**Notes from the google documentation** 
from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source#jsondatatable

*JSON Modifications
Google's helper libraries, and all queries sent to Google, return a slightly non-standard version of JSON/JSONP. If you are not parsing the returned code yourself, this should not matter to you. The Visualization API client supports both standard and the modified versions of JSON. Here is a summary of the differences:

JSON does not support JavaScript Date values (for example, "new Date(2008,1,28,0,31,26)"; the API implementation does. However, the API does now support a custom valid JSON representation of dates as a string in the following format: Date(year, month, day[,hour, minute, second[, millisecond]]) where everything after day is optional, and months are zero-based.

JSON uses double-quotes for dictionary keys; the API implementation uses unquoted keys.

JSON requires double-quotes around string values; the API implementation uses single     quotes.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually handle creating dates just like you would in standard Python - the API handles the conversion to JS for you. All you have to do is `import datetime` at the beginning of your script, change the column type for `year` from `string` to `date` and then create the dates as you would in standard Python:

```
# This is the first modification - importing the library
import datetime
import gviz_api

# page_template stays the same
# ...

def main():
  # Creating the data
  # Here we change the type of column "year" to "date"
  description = {"year": ("date", "Year"),
                 "sales": ("number", "Sales"),
                 "expenses": ("number", "Expenses")}

  # Here we switch out the string dates with an actual Python datetime.date
  # The conversion happens in the the subsequent functions, giving you a 
  # date that is usable in the JS
  data = [{"year": datetime.date(2007,3,7), "sales": 1000, "expenses": 300},
          {"year": datetime.date(2009,6,11), "sales": 1200, "expenses": 400},
          {"year": datetime.date(2009,3,1), "sales": 1300, "expenses": 500},
          {"year": datetime.date(2010,8,6), "sales": 1401, "expenses": 600},
          {"year": datetime.date(2011,7,13), "sales": 1500, "expenses": 800}]
  # Loading it into gviz_api.DataTable
  data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(description)
  data_table.LoadData(data)

  # Creating a JavaScript code string
  jscode = data_table.ToJSCode("jscode_data",
                               columns_order=("year", "sales", "expenses"),
                               order_by="year")
  # Creating a JSon string
  json = data_table.ToJSon(columns_order=("year", "sales", "expenses"),
                           order_by="year")

  # Putting the JS code and JSon string into the template
  print "Content-type: text/html"
  print
  print page_template % vars()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```